# python unittest : Assert the sequence of method calls in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a method which I am unit testing

```
def some_functionality():
    must_call_first()
    must_call_second()
```

My current approach

```
@patch('module.must_call_first', autospec=True)
@patch('module.must_call_second', autospec=True)
def test_some_functionality(patch_second,patch_first):
     # execute    
     some_functionality()

     # assert
     patch_first.assert_called_once()
     patch_second.assert_called_once()
```

Issue:

- The sequence of method-call for `must_call_first` and `must_call_second` will not be tested with my test case.
- If I change the actual method and change the order, my test case would still pass. But ideally, it should not!

Is there a way I can make sure that the `must_call_first` method was called before `must_call_second`.?

Comment: Replace them with the **same** `Mock` object and check the order of the `.call_list()`.